# What is the similar key type in Google Cloud Platform like Access Key to AWS?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace

I am trying to create an application where I have to access all the projects of Google Cloud Platform. 
I came up with an option of generating Service Accounts for all the Projects and add them to my project.

Is there any way to access all the Projects with one service token or a similar one just like AWS Access Key to access all the AWS projects at once?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this within an organisation via an org level service key.

https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/quickstart-organizations

Comment: The scope of this service account is limited for few GCP Services only. Is there any single account that can access all the services?